# Removing part of string in Google sheets starting from specific symbol

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a problem, I'm receiving massive data in shape

BA-01-01
BA-01-02
BA-02-01
WPS-01-01
WP-01-01
DA-01
DA-02

Where first 2-4 Letters are a Tag of product (BA), after, if product has different types we have number of type (01,02), and in the end if i have multiple location of product number of location (01,02,03).
And I need to calculate total amount of product with same Type. It can happen as you can see from screenshot below that some product dont have type, only tag So I need to remove from each product Id everything that goes after last "-"[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `REGEXREPLACE` as follows:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "-[^-]+$", "")
```

### Demo

The regex pattern `-[^-]+$` will match the last `-digit` term and then replace with empty string, to effectively remove it.

Comment: Great, just checked on part of project and it works perfect, thanks a lot, will update You it something will go wrong

Answer (score 0):

arrayformula mode:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "-[^-]+$", )))
```